# Installing windows 7 and MS visual studio 2010 on a virtual machine to work with openCV (especially SVM and SDM)

Tags: opencv, windows-7, virtual-machine, svm, 32-bit

I have MS Visual Studio 2012 installed on my laptop. But now I need MS Visual Studio 2010 . Because of this, I am thinking of downloading VMWare workstaion to create a Virtual Machine.
And, then I will be installing Windows 7 and then MS Visual Studio 2010 on it.

I wonder whether this is going to create a performance problem. The reason is that I will be using MS visual studio 2010 (in virtual machine) with openCV. There I need to use SVM (for training and predicting data- I've heard that this takes a LOT of time and memory. I'll be using like 300 colour images for this ). Will I be able to do all this on Virtual Machine ?
How much of memory do I need to allocate when creating the virtual machine ?

Actually, I had windows 8 (64-bit ) on my laptop when I first bought it. Since there was no 64-bit version after 2008 when it comes to MS Visual Studio ( I wanted at least 2012), I had to remove windows 8 (64-bit) from my laptop and then install windows 7 (32-bit). At the same time, I wanted to get rid of windows 8. Actually, this was not recommended by the manufacturer. But I had no other option. Now my laptop uses only 2.4 GB out of 4.0 GB memory. This happened due to that installation.

[image]

so, my question is : Since I have only 2.4 GB memory, will installing windows 7 on a virtual machine and then installing MS Visual Studio 2010 on top of it  create an issue ?
If it's fine, How much of memory should I allocate when creating the virtual machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend that you do not do this... that saying if you have absolutely no choice, technically it should work.

To run MS Visual Studio 2010 through the VM you'll need to allocate 1GB of RAM just for MS VS and another 512MB for the virtual machine.

Whenever you are not using the VM make sure you shut it down so it doesn't chew up that memory, because while it's running your host machine will have about 1.1GB left for itself.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks ! This is what even I was thinking...will have to look for some other way.